# Good Index funds in EU precisely in the Hungary area?

Tags: index-fund, vanguard, hungary

U.S citizens can easily purchase Vanguard index funds to invest and they are the most recommended. Are there any similar options for EU citizens, mainly Hungary? I am only getting familiar with the topic and find it difficult to map my options.

I am looking for index funds as they seem to be the most recommended on the internet.

Also I know Vanguard is available in the UK, but the minimum investment is a 100K GBP which is really not something I will have my hands on in the foreseeable future.

Thank you!

Comment: The usual way to find these is to google for "Country Stock Index".  "Hungary Stock Index" shows that Hungary's main index is called BUX.  You can then google for "BUX ETF" and it will turn up some links such as this one: http://bse.hu/topmenu/marketsandproducts/productbymarkets/equities/buxetfeng.html

Comment: @Eric Yea, I mainly see the BUX index around, which is the local one which **IF** I understand well, hasnt been performing that well and is also not as good as a Vanguard one?

Comment: I don't know enough about how Vanguard works in other countries, but I only see indexes in GBP, EUR and CHF.  I don't see any in Florints or any targeted specifically at Hungary.

Comment: Yea, I thought about eating the currency risk, I don't really know what to do. Probably more reading and research.

Comment: Which index do you want to track?

Comment: @Pepone I haven't made my choice as I am not sure what is available for me. That is what I need help with.

Comment: Hey Peter. I'm also interested in this. Did you manage to figure out anything further? If not I might have a teeny-tiny bit more info I could post here a bit later.

Comment: I landed on this question after googling. Since this happened 2 years ago, are you already investing in Vanguard? I started on the exact same search and would appreciate some guidance

Answer (score 4):

If you are still interested:
Open an account at Interactive Brokers (available from Hungary) and you can buy Vanguard ETFs.
Low costs - 1 USD per transaction. However, there is a 10 dollar monthly fee for the account.